# newLine() and CR/LF comparison

Tags: java, io, filewriter

Is the `BufferedWriter.newLine()` method in Java equals `CR/LF`? What's actually inside of that method?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/BufferedWriter.java#BufferedWriter.newLine%28%29 - I suggest attaching the source so you can view the source code of the JDK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

`BufferedWriter.newLine()` writes a line separator. This is not necessarily `"\r\n"`. Quoting [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine--):

> The line separator string is defined by the system property `line.separator`, and is not necessarily a single newline (`'\n'`) character.

The system property `line.separator` contains the line separator of the current OS by default.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of that method is:

```
 write(lineSeparator);
```

Where `lineSeparator` is an attribute of the BufferedWriter class that holds the `System.getProperty("line.separator");` value in the moment the buffer was opened.